# How to use inline CSS in Jade table data element?

Tags: css, node.js, pug

How do I set a table data element to a particular font color in jade? The `td` will have data fetched and rendered from DB.

```
table.table.table-striped#dashboardTable(style="width:100%")
          thead
            tr 
              th(style='width:15px') Account#
              th(style='width:65px') AccountNickName 
              th(style='width:5px') AccountOwner
          tbody
            for each in usersDocs
              tr
              span(style='color:orange')
                td #{each._id}
              td #{each.email}
              td #{each.firstName}
```

the `style=color:orange` isn't working. It is initially working as soon as I refresh the page but is reverting to black color which is the default link color in my **styles.css** file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be helpful to you

```
  table.table.table-striped#dashboardTable(style="width:100%")
      thead
        tr 
          th(style='width:15px') Account#
          th(style='width:65px') AccountNickName 
          th(style='width:5px') AccountOwner
      tbody
        for each in usersDocs
          tr.tabledata(style='color:red')  <!--here you can specify your color code or class name-->           
            td
              span(style='color:orange') #{each._id}
            td #{each.email}
            td #{each.firstName}
```